# React-router isActive method does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I use `es6`, `twitter bootstrap` and `react-router 1.0.0-rc3`. I want to create a navigation bar and add to `li` elements class `active`.

I tried to use `isActive` method of [history](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#history-mixin) object.

```
var RouterPropTypes = require('react-router').PropTypes;
```

**LinkWrapper component**

```
export class LinkWrapper extends React.Component{

  constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.to);
    console.log(this.props.query);
    let isActive = this.context.history.isActive(this.props.to, this.props.query);
    let className = isActive ? 'active' : '';
    return (<li className={className}>
                <CustomersIcon />
                <Link {...this.props}/>
            </li>);
  }
}

LinkWrapper.contextTypes = {
  history: RouterPropTypes.history
};
```

**NavBar component**

```
export class NavBar extends React.Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
      console.log('NavBar - componentDidUpdate');
    }

  render() {
    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
            <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navbar-collapse">
              <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                  <LinkWrapper href="customers" />
              </ul>
            </div>
      </nav>
    );     
  }
}

NavBar.contextTypes = {
  history: RouterPropTypes.history
}
```

On line `this.context.history.isActive` I get error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
```

because `this.props.to` and `this.props.query` are `'undefined'`.

I also tried to create LinkWrapper component in es5 with History Mixin, but this.props.to and this.props.query are still 'undefined'.

```
var Router = require('react-router');
var { Route, DefaultRoute, RouteHandler, Link, History } = Router;

const Tab = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ History ],
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.to);
    console.log(this.props.query);
    let isActive = this.history.isActive(this.props.to, this.props.query);
    let className = isActive ? 'active' : '';
    return (<li className={className}>
                <CustomersIcon />
                <Link {...this.props}/>
            </li>);
  }
});
```

Comment: edit: View my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use active class name

```
<Link ... activeClassName="active" />
```

if you want to use this.props.history, then you have to set history

```
// create browser history for navigating
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';
let history = createBrowserHistory();
```

then add history prop to router

```
<Router history={history}>
    <Route component={App} path="/">
        <Route component={indexView} path="/index" />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

then in a component like indexView you can do this

```
this.props.history.isActive('/someroute')
```